# Sorting List of objects with .notation based on inner list

Tags: c#, sorting, linq-to-objects

I've got these classes:

```
[DataContract]
public class RowData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string AuthServerName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string SecurityName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LastUser { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ClaimRelease { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<GameItem> Games { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class GameItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

I put my best guess non-working query of what it 'should' probably look like if I knew what I was doing.

```
public List<RowData> GetSortedByColumnList(Entities db, int ColumnID, string direction, int GameCount, List<RowData> rows)
{
...
    else if ((ColumnID > 3) && (ColumnID < GameCount + 4))
    {
        List<Game> gameslist = db.Games
            .Where(x => x.GameIsActive == 1)
            .ToList(); // Game has the key names

        int index = (ColumnID - GameCount) - 1; 

        // gamename is the name that i'd like to match for sorting purposes.
        string gamename = gameslist[index].GameName; 

        // *** LOOK HERE ****
        List<RowData> sortedList = rows
            .OrderBy(x => x.Games
                .Min(Games => Games.Version)
                .Where(Games => Games.Name == gamename))
            .ToList();

    rows = sortedList;
}
```

This is a sample of what rows will look like:

```
rows[0].id = 1
...
rows[0].Games[0].Name="A0"
rows[0].Games[0].Version=3
rows[0].Games[1].Name="B0"
rows[0].Games[1].Version=4

rows[1].id = 2
...
rows[1].Games[0].Name="A0"
rows[1].Games[0].Version=1
rows[0].Games[1].Name="B0"
rows[0].Games[1].Version=2

rows[2].id = 3
...
rows[2].Games[0].Name="A0"
rows[2].Games[0].Version=5
```

So if string gamename will equal "B0" and I will like the list to be sorted based on the version number so that the sorted order will be row[1], row[2], row[3]. Notice rows[2] doesn't have B0 in it.

How can I modify the query under the `// *** LOOK HERE ****` to get the list sorted as I want?

> Compile Error    1    'char' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension method 'Name' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: See the // *** LOOK HERE *** part of my code? The query underneath it is not compiling, but its my best guess as to the type of query that I would like to use. How can I fix it? Sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: If you're getting a compile error, you should add that to your question.  It will help us help you.

Comment: Your desired sort algorithm is also unclear... can you clarify what the sorting order should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are looking for a query which will return a list of games with a specific name in order of version, you are probably looking for something similar to the below:

```
List<GameItem> sortedList = rows
    .SelectMany(r => r.Games) // flattens to an ienumerable of games
    .Where(g => g.Name == gameName) // filters by the game name
    .OrderBy(g => g.Version) // orders by the game's version
    .ToList(); // converts the ienumerable to a list (of games).
```

If you wanted a `List<RowData>` instead, and we can assume there is only 1 game with a particular name per row, you could do something like below:

```
// delegate for generating orderby key    
Func<RowData, string, int> sortKey = (r, gn) =>
{
    var game = r.Games.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Name == gn);
    return game != null ? game.Version : int.MaxValue; // or "zzzzz" if version is a string (something to put it to the end of the list)
};

List<RowData> result = rows
    .OrderBy(r => sortKey(r, gameName))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah I wanted a List<RowData> returned. I'm going to give your second solution a shot right now :) Thank you!

Comment: The "return" line gives me an error stating that it cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'. (Version is a string btw ^_^)

Comment: I changed Func<RowData, string, int> to Func<RowData, string, string>

Comment: AND IT WORKED PERFECTLY! Thank you! Heroic there man! I really appreciate it :D